# Cartoon in the late 80's early 90's about dinosaurs with armour on

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, dinosaurs

When I was still in elementary school I would watch a cartoon which had these dinosaurs that would fight bad guys. They each wore metal armor on their bodies. They were all the same size but I can't recall if they were the same species of dinosaur.

I know later in the series their armor actually could combine with them in it to create a vehicle of some sort.

That is all I can remember; I don't remember the colors of the dinosaurs, just that they were all in small frame like they used to do and were all the same size. Any help would be appreciated.

- I know it isn't Dinosaucers.
- It's not Dino Riders because the cartoon I remember had small talking dinosaurs with metal armour on them.
- They were living creatures so it also wasn't Dinobots either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer. It was *[The Adventures of T. Rex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_T-Rex#Episode_list)*. Thank you for everyone's help.

[image: green, blue, yellow, pink, and purple T-Rexes in metal armor]